# Types of pipelining?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, cpu-pipelines

if pipelining is devided to polyfunctional pipelining and monofunctional pipelining(im sorry im not a native speaker the name may be incorect)
and the polyfunctional pipelining is futher devided to STATIC and DYNAMIC, then what is the differance between static and dynamic and what is the overall differance between poly and monofunctional?

Comment: I have never heard the terminology above, but I think it means static vs dynamic pipelining. Then this thread seems relevant: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/whats-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-pipelines

Comment: ok, thank you, maybe my teacher was wrong or ment something different because i couldnt find anything above these two :)

Comment: I think the usual English language terms for what you call "monofunctional" and "polyfunctional" are "scalar" and "superscalar". This is just a guess, because I honestly don't know how you use those terms.

Comment: well in my language it could be transfered as : a type of pipeling that does two functions at the same time and the other type is a type that does only one function at a time, you could say. But this is a definition of static and dynamic pipelining so thats why im confused O.o